# Bluetooth works only in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, bluetooth

I have tried a few distros like Ubuntu,Pop,Elementary and Bluetooth worked on none of them, mostly, they said No adapters were found. When I installed Debian, I put the rtl_bt folder from downloaded linux firmware in the /lib/firmware in Debian and then ran the following commands

```
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

And the bluetooth started working perfectly, however, even if I repeat the same steps on any other distro, none of them is able to run bluetooth. Why does it work only on Debian and how can I run bluetooth on other distributions too?

I have a HP Laptop which shows Realtek 4.2 bluetooth adapter in device manager of windows.

Here is the output of sudo lsmod | grep bluetooth in ubuntu

```
bluetooth             557056  11 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
ecdh_generic           28672  1 bluetooth
```

Output of sudo dmesg | grep Bluetooth is:

```
[  557.907762] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  557.907791] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  557.907795] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  557.907797] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  557.907800] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  590.467584] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  590.467587] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  590.467596] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Output of sudo systemctl status bluetooth is :

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-04-23 01:57:22 UTC; 10min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 5013 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 2.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─5013 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Apr 23 01:57:22 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Apr 23 01:57:22 ubuntu bluetoothd[5013]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Apr 23 01:57:22 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Apr 23 01:57:22 ubuntu bluetoothd[5013]: Starting SDP server
Apr 23 01:57:23 ubuntu bluetoothd[5013]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

Here are some details I found in HP Support Assistant about the pc model:

```
HP Laptop 15-da1xxx 
Product number: 7MW54PA#ACJ
Serial number: CND9304LP0
```

[image: This is the bluetooth detail in windows device manager]

Comment: Please copy&paste the commands and the corresponding output. (Do you really have `Sudo` with an uppercase `S`?) Do you get any error messages when you use the other distributions. Ubuntu is based on Debian, so normally all things that work in Debian should work in Ubuntu as well. Please tell us the exact versions you used.

Comment: Realtek driver issues are very common in Linux,. Please run _sudo lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 && lsusb -v_ then copy the text, return here, click [edit] and paste the result into your question. It would also be nice to know the model part number of that HP laptop; please copy that from the serial number sticker, as model numbers anywhere else on the laptop are marketing buzzwords and don't tell us enough to find your hardware manual.

Comment: It is sudo with lowercase 's' and the ubuntu version I used was 19.04 as well as 19.10,Pop!_OS was 19.10 the Debian version on which bluetooth worked was 10.3 Buster